# How to install avahi-browse on oracle linux 8

Tags: oracle-linux, avahi

I need to install `avahi-browse` on a new oracle linux 8 machine. I have installed `avahi` package, that only provides `avahi-daemon`

I have tried `dnf search avahi`, but the found packages (`avahi-devel`, `avahi-glib`, `avahi-gobject`, `avahi-libs`, `avahi-ui`, `avahi-autoipd`, `avahi-compat-*`) did not contain `avahi-browse`.

`dnf provides avahi-browse` did not find any matches.

I added [EPEL repository](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-on-oracle-linux/), with the same results.

Do you know what repository/package contains `avahi-browse`?